# Is there any support for Google Tag Manager in apple tv?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, apple-tv

I need to integrate Google Tag Manager in Apple TV, but I am not sure if there is a library for that.

There is one for Google Analytics, but I would like to use Google Tag Manager.

Answer (score 0):

The [developer pages at Google](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/) do not mention an SDK für tvOS, and on Apple TV there are no webviews.

So I'm going out on a limb and say no, there is no such library.